# Hibernate MANUAL flushmode behaves like AUTO

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate

I'm trying to update a table using HQL and want to set the Flush mode to MANUAL. I've tried 2 approaches.

```
// Update user via session
em.unwrap(Session.class).createQuery("update User u set u.numRecords =:numRecords where u.id = 1")
    .setParameter("numRecords", new Random().nextInt(1234567))
    .setHibernateFlushMode(FlushMode.MANUAL)
    .executeUpdate();

// Update user via entity manager.
Query query = em
    .createQuery("update User u set u.numRecords =:numRecords where u.id = 1")
    .setParameter("numRecords", new Random().nextInt(1234567));
((QueryImpl) query).setFlushMode(FlushMode.MANUAL).executeUpdate();
```

My caller is calling these 2 methods as follows -

```
@Transactional
public void foo() {
    userRepository.updateUserViaSession();
    userRepository.clear();
}

@Transactional
public void foo2() {
    userRepository.updateUserViaEntityManager();
    userRepository.clear();
}
```

Entity -

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User {
    @Id
    private Long id;
    private String email;
    private int numRecords;
    private int numAllowedRecords;
}
```

The problem is that when I call either foo() or foo2(), Hibernate flushes the update immediately instead of waiting for me to explicitly call flush(). Why is this the case?

Comment: I guess that `@Transactional` annotation force flushing. Also you did not show implementation of the `userRepository.clear()` method.

Comment: userRepository.clear() is calling em.clear(). @Transactional will force flush only at the very end. But I'm calling clear() before that happens so the flush() should do nothing. But DB is actually being updated. Anyway I can see from the DB logs that flush is actually happening in the middle of the transaction, which is weird since it's MANUAL.

Comment: That's weird, never ran in an issue like that. . . I know that it may sound a bit dumb and perhaps doesn't fit for your use case, but have you tried to set flush mode to `MANUAL` directly in the Session and EntityManager, instead of setting to the query? Again, I know that may sound a bit stupid and perhaps doesn't fit for your needs, but try it out and check if the same issue happens.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's not how `FlushMode` works.

Setting the `FlushMode` on a query controls whether or not the persistence context should be flushed *before* query execution. It has no effect on *when* the query executes. JPA *always* executes queries *immediately*.

Overriding the `FlushMode` is useful when you don't want the query to see changes made within the current context. By default, JPA assumes all changes made so far should be seen by the query, and so it flushes the context just before the execution to ensure that.

Comment: Is there a reference for the statement - "JPA always executes queries immediately."? From https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.1/userguide/html_single/chapters/flushing/Flushing.html, it says AUTO flush happens "prior to executing a JPQL/HQL query that overlaps with the queued entity actions". That implies JPQL will not always execute queries immediately, only on overlap.

Comment: "AUTO flush happens **prior to executing a JPQL/HQL query** that overlaps with the queued entity actions". It doesn't say anything about when the query gets executed, only when the flush happens

Comment: Thanks. What controls when a jpa queries executes?

Comment: As I already said, queries are always executed immediately. Frankly, I don't quite see why you would expect them to be delayed when you can simply call them later in your code

Comment: Is there a reference for "queries are always executed immediately"?

Comment: There is no reference that says that explicitly, because there's no need for that. There are three methods of executing queries: calling `getSingleResult()`, `getResultList()`, and `executeUpdate()`, which returns the number of rows affected. Each of those returns the result of the query to the caller, which implies the query cannot have been scheduled for a later time

Comment: Makes sense. So I guess the only way to delay things are to update the entity directly instead of issuing JPA/HQL/native statements. Thanks.